# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status [gem5]

Tags: gcc, gem5

I am building gem5.opt using

```
scons build/X86/gem5.opt
```

I got the following error:

```
[    LINK]  -> X86/marshal
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [build/X86/marshal] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I tried linking libpng.so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/libpng.so
```

This ofcourse tells me that it is incompatible:

```
[    LINK]  -> X86/marshal
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpng.so when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/libpng.so when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libpng.so when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../libpng.so when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libpng.so when searching for -lpng
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 [    LINK]  -> X86/cpu/testers/memtest/lib.o.partial
 [     CXX] X86/dev/pci/device.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/dev/pci/host.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/dev/pci/copy_engine.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/systemc/channel/sc_event_queue.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/systemc/channel/sc_in_resolved.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/systemc/channel/sc_inout_resolved.cc -> .o
scons: *** [build/X86/marshal] Error 1
 [     CXX] X86/systemc/channel/sc_out_resolved.cc -> .o
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So where do I get 64-bit libpng.so from?

```
git SHA: af8d107191cc69a77624e2af34f108dc9c1ff03f
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

Edit: I don't know if [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=gem5-dev@gem5.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5Bgem5%5C-dev%5C%5D+Change+in+gem5%5C%2Fgem5%5C%5Bmaster%5C%5D%5C%3A+scons%5C%3A+Move+the+marshal+binary+to+the+build+directory%22&o=newest) will help but putting it here just in case.

Comment: Weird, I was using Ubuntu 18.04 for a while, but I never saw this problem, it tends to be well supported. I would also recommend that you try to use the following scons options: `scons -j1 --verbose`, which will clearly show you the exact failing GCC commands. I would then try to understand from that what is going on. You do have libpng-dev installed I'm assuming? Here is a working [Ubuntu 18.04 Docker setup just in case](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/3fdd83c2c58327d9714fa2347c724b78d7c05e2b#docker).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. Passing the correct path of png lib will not solve the problem and the building process will still throw an error massage that says "`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`"
I solved this problem just by adding `sudo` at the beginning of build command!!!

```
sudo scons build/X86/gem5.opt --force-lto
```

result:

```
scons: Building targets ...
 [VER TAGS]  -> X86/sim/tags.cc
 [     CXX] X86/sim/tags.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/base/date.cc -> .o
 [    LINK]  -> X86/gem5.opt
scons: done building targets.
```